# Storing string into hashmap with occurrences

Tags: java, string, sorting, split, hashmap

I have a method that returns some kind of string. I want to store the individual words in a HashMap with their number of occurrences?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{link:hagdjh, matrics:[{name:apple, value:1},{name:jeeva, value:2},{name:abc, value:0}]}";

        String[] strs = s.split("matrics");
        System.out.println("Substrings length:" + strs.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(strs[i]);
        }

    }
```

For eg, I have a string- "{link:https://www.google.co.in/, matrics:[{name:apple, value:1},{name:graph, value:2},{name:abc, value:0}]}";

```
Now my hashmap should look like

apple = 1
graph = 2
abc = 0
```

How should I proceed?

I know how to use HashMaps. My problem, in this case, is that I don't know how to parse through the given string and store the words with their number of occurrences.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: That the sample String resembles a JSON String does not mean that all the input is JSON – therefore a JSON parser may not be the solution …

Comment: My suggestion is,you should use object mapper by making separate class

Comment: @tquadrat - I agree with you. I've posted a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580554/storing-string-into-hashmap-with-occurrences/60581187#60581187

Comment: The task is *not* to count the words in an arbitrary String, the task is to *parse* a (JSON?) String that holds some words together with their occurence  (in perhaps a different text). – I suggest to update the text of the question accordingly …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("matrics:\\[\\{(.*?)\\]\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern
                .matcher("{link:hagdjh, matrics:[{name:apple, value:1},{name:jeeva, value:2},{name:abc, value:0}]}");
        String data = "";
        if (matcher.find()) {
            data = matcher.group();
        }
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
        pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            records.add(matcher.group());
        }
        for (String s : records) {
            String[] parts = s.split(", ");
            map.put(parts[0].substring(parts[0].indexOf(":") + 1),
                    Integer.parseInt(parts[1].substring(parts[1].indexOf(":") + 1)));
        }
        map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
apple = 1
jeeva = 2
abc = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "\\{name:(.*), value:(\\d+)\\}";
            HashMap<String, Integer> link = new HashMap<>();

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

            while (matcher.find()){
                String found = matcher.group(1);
                String number = matcher.group(2);
                link.put(found, Integer.parseInt(number));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appeares that your data is in JSON format.

If it is guaranteed to be in JSON format, you can parse it using JSON parsing library and than analyze the matrics data in a convinient way (code follows).

If the data is not guaranteed to be in JSON format, you can use REGEX to help you parse it, as in Reza soumi's answer.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.HashMap;

String s = "{link:hagdjh, matrics:[{name:apple, value:1},{name:jeeva, value:2},{name:abc, value:0}]}";

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray matrics = obj.getJSONArray("matrics");
System.out.println(matrics);

HashMap<String, Integer> matricsHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i=0;i < matrics.length();i++){
    JSONObject matric = matrics.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("Adding matric: " + matric + " to hash map");
    String matricName = matric.getString("name");
    Integer matricValue = Integer.valueOf(matric.getInt("value"));
    matricsHashMap.put(matricName, matricValue);
}

System.out.println(matricsHashMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import static java.lang.System.err;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

/**
 *  Counting the words in a String.
 */
public class CountWordsInString
{
        /*-----------*\
    ====** Constants **========================================================
        \*-----------*/
    /**
     *  An empty array of {@code ${type_name}} objects.
     */
    public static final String INPUT = "{link:https://www.google.co.in/, matrics:[{name:apple, value:1},{name:graph, value:2},{name:abc, value:0}]}";

        /*---------*\
    ====** Methods **==========================================================
        \*---------*/
    /**
     *  The program entry point.
     *
     *  @param  args    The command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main( final String... args )
    {
        try
        {
            final var result = stream( INPUT.split( "\\W+" ) )
                .filter( s -> !s.isBlank() )
                .filter( s -> !s.matches( "\\d*" ) )
                .collect( groupingBy( s -> s ) )
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect( toMap( k -> k.getKey(), v -> Long.valueOf( v.getValue().size() ) ) );
            out.println( result.getClass() );
            for( final var entry : result.entrySet() )
            {
                out.printf( "'%s' occurred %d times%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
            }
        }
        catch( final Throwable t )
        {
            //---* Handle any previously unhandled exceptions *----------------
            t.printStackTrace( err );
        }
    }   //  main()
}
//  class CountWordsInString
```

Confessed, not the most obvious solution, but I wanted to have some fun with it, too.

The `INPUT.split( "\\W+" )` gives you the words in the string, but also numbers and an 'empty' word at the beginning.

The 'empty' word is eliminated with the first `filter()` statement, the numbers go with the second.

The first `collect( groupingBy() )` gives you a `HashMap<String,List<String>>`, so I had to convert that to a `HashMap<String,Long>` in the following steps (basically with the second `collect( groupingBy() )`).

May be there is a more efficient solution, or one that is more elegant, or even one that is both, more efficient and more elegant … but it works as expected, and I had some fun with it.

The output is:

```
class java.util.HashMap
'apple' occurred 1 times
'matrics' occurred 1 times
'abc' occurred 1 times
'in' occurred 1 times
'www' occurred 1 times
'name' occurred 3 times
'link' occurred 1 times
'google' occurred 1 times
'https' occurred 1 times
'co' occurred 1 times
'value' occurred 3 times
'graph' occurred 1 times
```